# Parsing date with arrabic or chinese char

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to parse date like the following :

```
["2014-11-28T午後6:04:16.952+0900" ,
 "2014-11-29T4:00:47,458 p.m.-0500" ,
 "٢٠١٤-١١-٢٨T٠٤:١٤:٥٢.١٧٤+0300" ]
```

For the two first date, I can write something like :

```
DateTime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT午後%H:%M:%S').to_time.to_s]
DateTime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').to_time.to_s]
```

But it make me lost PM and zone information. For the last date in arrabic, i don't know how i can process.

Any idea?

Comment: that's arabic, not yiddish...

Comment: Ok, i've edit the question. Sorry for that.